# Why is this Java program gives incorrect results on Eclipse and correct results when run from terminal?

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, character-encoding

Consider the following program.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {       
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
        char[] array = new char[3];
        array[0] = '\u0905';
        array[1] = '\u0905';
        array[2] = '\u0905';
        CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(array);
        Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        ByteBuffer encoded = utf8.encode(charBuffer);
        System.out.println(new String(encoded.array()));

    }
}
```

When I execute this using terminal,

```
java HelloWorld
```

I get properly encoded, shaped text. Default encoding was `MacRoman`.

Now when I execute the same code from Eclipse, I see incorrect text getting printed to the console.

[image: Eclipse console showing scrambled text]

When I change the file encoding option of Eclipse to `UTF-8`, it prints correct results in Eclipse.

I am wondering why this happens? Ideally, file encoding options should not have affected this code because here I am using UTF-8 explicitly.

Any idea why this is happening?

I am using Java 1.6 (Sun JDK), Mac OSx 10.7.

Comment: "Default encoding was MacRoman" <-- uh, what charset is that?

Comment: In your last line, can you append a specific `Charset` to the `String` constructor (for instance, `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`? What is the result then?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify what encoding you want to use when creating the string:

```
new String(encoded.array(), charset)
```

otherwise it will use the default charset.

Comment: Meh, I gave that as a comment :p +1

Comment: Note: (well, you may already know that...) UTF-8 in JDK 7 is `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. With lesser versions this has to be `Charset.forName("UTF-8")...

Comment: I have already tried adding the charset when creating string. In that case, From Eclipse, it works. From terminal, it just prints "???". This works from command line `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 HelloWorld`.

Comment: @Appu Probably because your terminal's font does not support that specific character. Your original code was working but was not printing the right character.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the console you use to display the output is also encoded in UTF-8. In Eclipse for example, you need to go to Run Configuration > Common to do this.

[image]

Comment: He mentioned that *When I change the file encoding option of Eclipse to UTF-8, it prints correct results in Eclipse.*

Comment: This fixed it. Looks like console encoding gets inherited from file's encoding. When file encoding changes, console encoding also changed to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("\u0905\u0905\u0905");
```

would be the straight-forward usage.

And encoding is missing for the String constructor, defaulting to the set default encoding.

```
new String(encoded.array(), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: When you say `System.out.println("\u0905\u0905\u0905");`, I think it gets converted to the default encoding. There is no guarantee that it will be UTF-8 encoded. That's why I have used `CharSet` to force the encoding. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Interestingly, when adding `UTF-8` to the `new String(encoded.array())`, it prints just `???` from terminal. Which is weird!!

Comment: @Appu the encoding is a mapping between bytes and characters. `\u905` is already a (unicode) character so you don't need to specify an encoding to create a string from it. You would need to specify an encoding if you wanted to convert it to a `byte[]`...

Comment: Yes, @assylias is right: byte[] is binary data, String is text - and of course Java chose Unicode internally (for all text). char is 16-bit Unicode (UTF-16), String constants are stored compacter in UTF-8. An ecdlipse IDE console, a Windows application and a DOS command line can use different encodings. Internally they mix things, use C char[] which actually is byte[] + a platform encoding. Java gives a `?` for unconvertible Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Eclipse uses the default ANSI encoding, not UFT-8. If your using a different encoding than what your IDE is using, you will get unreadable results.

Comment: Apart from the spelling errors here "your", could you give a link as to your statement that "Eclipse uses the default ANSI encoding"? And in 2013, who uses ASCII as a default anyway?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your console run configuration.

- click on "Run"
- click on "Run Configurations" and then click on "common" tab
- change Encoding to UTF
  [image]